# opera developer browser assistant process: how to remove it 'permanently'

Tags: browser, opera

Irrespective of whether Opera browser (Version 52.0.2871.99) is open or closed, in task manager -- processes it shows "opera developer browser assistant" active.  Maybe, it is a background process. I am using Windows 7.

In settings, I tried to find a suitable option to disable it but could not locate.

Any advice for how to disable or remove it 'permanently'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Win7 laptop. I opened the program list and typed msconfig in the *search programs and files* box. At the next window that opened, I clicked on the 3rd tab labeled Startup, scrolled down the list and unchecked the Opera Browser Assistant box. After restart, no more funky red O in my tray.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled it in Task Manager/Startup tab - seemed to work - assume you're running WIN 10? I have used Opera for years but I'm unhappy about them sneaking in that process as well.

Comment: This works only until a new version of Opera is installed. Then a new/different startup entry is created and you need to disable it again! It would be nice if Opera would add an option to keep is disabled!

Comment: Didn't work for me in W8.1: showing as Disabled in Taskmanager Startup tab, icon is still in notification tray. After several reboots.  Someone said it doesn't happen with opera portable? https://www.ghacks.net/2020/03/12/what-is-opera-browser-assistant-and-how-to-disable-it/